# Find index of first bigger row of current value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

I have big dataset of values as follow:

[image]

column "bigger" would be index of the first row with bigger "bsl" than "mb" from current row. I need to do it without loop as I need it to be done in less than a second. by loop it's over a minute.

For example for the first row (with index 74729) the bigger is going to be 74731. I know it can be done by linq in C# but I'm almost new in python.

here is another example:

[image]

here is text version:

```
index       bsl     mb              bigger
74729   47091.89    47160.00        74731.0
74730   47159.00    47201.00        74735.0
74731   47196.50    47201.50        74735.0
74732   47186.50    47198.02        74735.0
74733   47191.50    47191.50        74735.0
74734   47162.50    47254.00        74736.0
74735   47252.50    47411.50        74736.0
74736   47414.50    47421.00        74747.0
74737   47368.50    47403.00        74742.0
74738   47305.00    47310.00        74742.0
74739   47292.00    47320.00        74742.0
74740   47302.00    47374.00        74742.0
74741   47291.47    47442.50        74899.0
74742   47403.50    47416.50        74746.0
74743   47354.34    47362.50        74746.0
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example as text or, better, DataFrame constructor.

Comment: This is still not a text-based reproducible input. How many rows do you have in the actual dataset?

Comment: @mozway it's in text, the actual dataset can be up 200k

Comment: Hmm, then a broadcasting approach will be difficult as it consumes O(n^2) of memory

Comment: How far away do you expect the "next' index to be? Is there a threshold?

Comment: it can be up to ~200 sometime but there is no threshold or limitation

Comment: Then you can apply the broadcasting method to only the next ~200 rows. That will decrease dramatically the number of comparisons (sorry I can't update my code for now)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many rows you have, but if the number is reasonable, you can perform a pairwise comparison:

```
# get data as arrays
a = df['bsl'].to_numpy()
b = df['mb'].to_numpy()
idx = df.index.to_numpy()

# compare values and mask lower triangle
# to ensure comparing only the greater indices
out = np.triu(a>b[:,None]).argmax(1).astype(float)

# reindex to original indices
idx = idx[out]
# mask invalid indices
idx[out<np.arange(len(out))] = np.nan

df['bigger'] = idx
```

Output:

```
   bsl  mb  bigger
0    1   2     2.0
1    2   4     6.0
2    3   3     5.0
3    2   1     3.0
4    3   5     NaN
5    4   2     5.0
6    5   1     6.0
7    1   0     7.0
```